# "an hour and a half" or "one and a half hours"

Tags: meaning-in-context, time, mathematics

Are both `"an hour and a half"` and `"one and a half hours"` correct? If so, is either more appropriate in different contexts?

Example context:

> "The Superbowl starts in less than one and a half hours."
>
> "The Superbowl starts in less than an hour and a half."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both of these are equally good with *hours* and other common measurements.  But maybe not with less common measurements.  For example:

> He drank one and a half glasses of water.

is more common than

> He drank a glass and a half of water.

Comment: Your second example seems flawed; shouldn't it be "He drank a glass and a half of water"?

Answer (score 4):

The are both correct, and interchangeable; assuming you mean *90 minutes*. *One* and *an* indicate the same singular quantity.

Comment: Should we use Ninety minutes,two years etc. as plural or singular?

Comment: In what context? You used a plural here.

Comment: Ok you mean we can use both singular and plural for them. for example Two years is/are a long time. 2. two hours have/has been passed since he had fallen asleep

Comment: @starun008 *Two years are a long time* doesn't work for me on its' own. But if we spent two years on something, it might. Two hours may have passed, but I hope I'm never a [has-been](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/has-been).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that one is more likely to be used by certain people and not others. In the UK, sentences like

> "The Superbowl (or anything else) starts in less than an hour and a
>   half."

are more common and natural.

Comment: Do you have any examples of where ‘one and a half hours’ would be more common? I cannot think of any dialect or context where ‘an hour and a half’ doesn’t sound more natural.

Comment: Janus, I meant that the "in less than an hour and a half" wording would be more common.