# Is the phrase, "one and half an hour" correct?

Tags: grammar, time

For example:

> It might take one and half an hour to do this.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not. It might take ***one and a half hours*** to do it.

Comment: It might, if was an answer to something like "*How many people and how long might it take to change a fuse on this contraption?*" The answer you've highlighted could do with a comma after the word *one*, though.

Comment: Related: [“an hour and a half” or “one and a half hours”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/149494/191178)

Comment: Correct in what sense?  From the functional point of view, it's absolutely correct if the speaker gets his message across with no misunderstanding. It is pretty hard to misunderstood "one and half an hour",  and Language is actually about communicating,   not constructing grammatically correct utterances, however helpful they are–as a subsidiary notion . Quite a few of our utterances are not complete sentences. I mention this, because most grammars take the complete sentence as the basic building block to "learning" English. Which,  of, course, they're not.

Comment: However,  learning how natives speak improves comprehensibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, singular is to be used when there is **one and only one** subject. Thus, you should say

> It might take one and a half hour**s** to do this.

Note that this rule varies from a language to the other. In French for example, singular is to be used when there is **less than two subjects**. In French, you would say:

> Il faut une *heure* et demi pour faire ceci.

The word *heure* (the French for *hour*) is singular here.

But this isn't a good example, because of the phrase *"une heure et demi"*, which means *"an hour and a half"*. Here's a better one:

> He is 1.78 meter**s** tall.
>
> Il mesure 1.78 mètre.

Comment: In English one/an hour and a half is also used.

Comment: Oh, right. I edited the answer to it clearer.